# How to check object type in VB Script

Tags: object, vbscript, typeof

I am passing one object to function which needs to take action according to object type. e.g. If object is of "Scripting.Dictionary" then count keys and if it is "Scripting.FileSystemObject" then close it.

In short as like typeof in c# and variableName.class in java, how we can find which scripting object we are using ?

Comment: TypeName works for pre-define data types. when you use TypeName for Scripting.Dictionory object it will return you type is object. I would like to check what type of object it is.

Answer (score 4):

Use the [`TypeName`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y58s1cs6) function to get the type of a variable.

> **TypeName Function**
>
> Returns a string that provides **Variant** subtype information about a variable.
>
> ```
> TypeName(varname)
> ```

Comment: Obvious duplicate why encourage this behaviour?, just flag the question and move on.